# could not find function "some Function" from some package

Tags: r

I am encountering an error when creating a data frame. I was running some package one day back everything was good but now I am having some issues like not able to find some function. I suspect its coz of my R studio (Ver. 1.2.5033). What do you think?
After loading some packages I can't access functions associated with them.
Best:
Imran

require(package)
could not find function "package's function"

Comment: Hi Imran, it has nothing to do with RStudio. Try reinstalling the package you're looking for. Also, you should use `library()` instead of `require()`.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. sessioninfo() help me to identify if the package was loaded during my analysis. I appreciate your time and help me in this trouble shooting.